# AccessViolation Exception in wpf while connecting to db due to multiple threads

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I am working on a multithreaded wpf application I get "AccessViolationException" saying Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
in my ConnectionOpen().
my code is as follows.

```
public class DatabaseServices
{
    static SQLiteConnection connection;
    static object conLock = new object();
    static object conCloseLock = new object();

    public static SQLiteDataReader ConnectionOpen(string Query)
    {
        lock (conLock)
        {


            if (connection != null && connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database/abc.sqlite");
                connection.Open();
            }
            else if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database/abc.sqlite");
                connection.Open();
            }
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, connection);
            SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();


            return sqlite_datareader;
        }
    }

    public static void ConnectionClose()
    {
        lock (conCloseLock)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

I've used lock as well for thread safe code but its not working.why?

Answer (score 1):

The `SQLiteConnection` is not thread safe. Like all other database connections, you are supposed to open one per thread. The fact that your code has a few parts that won't work even if it *were* thread safe, does not help either. For example, anybody can close a connection, while somebody else is just querying on it.

Keep to the well-established patterns. Do not use database connections across threads. Do not write your own connection caching. Open a conection, do your work and then close it. If you definetly need connection caching, look into the documentation of your database and find out how the inbuilt mechanism works.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not support Multiple Active ResultSets (MARS)

So you cannot have multiple DataReaders served by the same connection.

After connecting (and dropping the lock) you hand out a DataReader. I assume the client code calls this ConnectionOpen method twice resulting (or rather attempting) to re-use the same connection.

Create a connection per DataReader.

When you use connection pooling:

```
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;
```

connections will be recycled/pooled when closed properly. This will lessen the overhead of the creation and opening of the connections.